# Oracle Pl/SQL Exception Flow

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11gr2

Given a simple SP like;

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TEST1
AS
BEGIN
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'truncate table missingtable';
   dbms_output.put_line('here');
EXCEPTION
   WHEN OTHERS THEN
      IF SQLCODE != -942 THEN
         RAISE;
      END IF;
END;
```

I never get to the output statement, I thought control returned to the same block, which is the only block.. and yes, missingtable reports a -942 if I try to truncate it.

Comment: Where do you want to return the control in the same block and why?

Comment: [After an exception handler runs, control transfers to the next statement of the enclosing block (or to the invoker or host environment if there is no enclosing block)](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/errors.htm#LNPLS851)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's a logic problem, in fact the exception happens but you coded to raise an exception only if the return code is different of 942 which is the the error happening.

if you want to continue to the dbms_output in you first block you need an inner exception

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TEST1
AS
BEGIN
   BEGIN
     EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'truncate table missingtable';
   EXCEPTION
      WHEN OTHERS THEN
          IF SQLCODE != -942 THEN
             RAISE;
          ELSE
             NULL;
          END IF;
    END;
    
    dbms_output.put_line('here');
END;
/
```

Comment: The exception is a -942, so shouldn't it handle the error, then return control to the next statement, dbms_output...  I wish to continue with more code and only truncate the table if present.  I could do this with a catalog lookup but thought the exception handler would work.

Comment: Ahhh does the continuation code need to come after the exception block?

Comment: No if there is an exception it does not return to the next statement, I added an exemple to my answer

Comment: you need inner EXCEPTION blocks if you want to handle specific exception for a statement or series of statements, in your exemple the dbms_output is part of the same block so as soon as the exception happens oracle execute the exception block and exists